# "You have an error in your SQL syntax" при выполнении SELECT запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Возникает данная ошибка

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc'

Вот код

```
$list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM News desc") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($list))
{
printf("<td>
<table class='newscount'>
<tr>
<td class='date'>
<span class='datetext'>%s</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div class='textnews'>%s</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>", $row['date'], $row['text']);
}
```

Comment: @Vlmake, а вы реально что ли не смогли самостоятельно прочитать ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно. "You have an error in your SQL syntax" - У вас шибка в коде SQL.

```
$list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM News") or die(mysql_error());
```

DESC - Зарезервированное слово, используется для указания направления сортировки в совместно с ORDER BY.

Comment: Всё равно такая же ошибка

>$list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM News  LIMIT 6 ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: А из какой документации вы черпаите вдохновение? LIMIT точно должен так работать?